# No sound digital output (S/PDIF) UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound

Heyy so i installed the UBUNTU 20.04 LTS & i don't have sound with the digital output (s/pdif) but i have only the sound when i plug my headphone on the line out entry
[Alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPVa6.png)

Thank you

Comment: I don't know of any Nvidia devices that have a S/PDIF output.  Are you sure that you have selected the correct sound device?